# Is there a way to disable the sending of ResendRequest Message?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

---

> **Resend Request** logic is the FIX session mechanism by which a given
>   system, upon detecting a higher than expected message sequence number
>   from its counterparty, requests a range of ordered messages resent
>   from the counterparty. The counterparty resends the requested message
>   range sequentially until both systems are back in sequence

As the market I'm working on wants to rely only on the **NextExpectedMsgSeqNum**, is there a way to disable the sending of **ResendRequest** messages by **Quickfix** engine?

i.e. :   Configuration parameter: ***EnableResendRequest=Y|N***

Comment: I don't think so.  ResendRequest is part of the FIX specification.  It sounds like your counterparty is intentionally doing FIX wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added this parameter **SendRedundantResendRequests=N** to my Quickfix settings file. It's efficient, so i can avoid the sending of this message.

Comment: You don't understand the existence of `ResendRequest` and disabling it is going to open a can of worms later.

Comment: @DumbCoder, Yes, the normal behevior is to use  the ResendRequest messages. But,  now, we're working with  specific market  which doesn't  use this type of messages to resynchronize with the counterparty.